# How to fix "class does not support automation or does not support expected interface"

Tags: excel, vba, object, export

One of my Macros is giving me the error "class does not support automation or does not support expected interface" when I try to export a Worksheet as PDF.

I moved my excel inventory file from a MacBook that was running Windows 7 to a PC running Windows 10. The macros that I use on the daily all worked except one which consisted of exporting a sheet to PDF. I researched the error and found out that there could be a problem with the dll files since I moved from Windows 7 to Windows 10 which made sense because that same macro worked fine for months on my Windows 7 machine.
The full error was:
"Run-time error '430':
class does not support automation or does not support expected interface."
I am not very experienced when it comes to exe and dll files, so I could not find a way to 'update' them

```
Sub ExportPDFProforma()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets("Sheet1").Select

Dim ExportName As String

If Range("B5").Value = "" Then
    ExportName = "Test"
Else
    ExportName = Range("B5").Value
End If

Sheets("Sheet1").Copy Before:=Sheets(1)
Sheets("Sheet1 (2)").Select
Sheets("Sheet1 (2)").Move After:=Sheets(5)
Sheets("Sheet1 (2)").Select
Sheets("Sheet1 (2)").Name = "Print Preview"
Range("A1:L49").Select
Range("L49").Activate
Selection.Copy
ActiveSheet.Paste
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Call PreviewFormatting

Dim Shp As Shape

For Each Shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
If Not Shp.Type = msoPicture Then
Shp.Delete
End If
Next Shp

If Range("B4") = "x" Then
Call HideBlankRows(Range("F14:F23"), Range("D36:D45"))
Else
Call HideBlankRows(Range("F14:F23"), Range("D34:D43"))
End If

Worksheets("Print Preview").Activate
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="C:\...", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

Range("A1:B1").Select

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("Print Preview").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The error lines are:

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="C:\...", 
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

It might also just be a syntax error somewhere because of the newer version of VB on Windows 10.
Does anybody know a way to fix it or a way around it?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. I cannot see the full code to analize so have a look at mine maybe you will spot some differences.

```
Option Explicit
Sub ExportPDF()
Dim PDFFile as String

PDFFile = “C:\someFolder\MyFile.PDF”
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PDFFile, 
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=OpenPDFAfterCreating

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried to replace my code with yours but it still returned the same problem. I added the full code in the main question to see if there's something I'm missing.

Comment: @MichelChalfoun check the line where you put the file path. **Filename:=“C:\someFolder\myFilr.PDF”**

Comment: i checked it and it worked on my other computer fine. I just am not posting it on the question here. It includes a 2 strings and a variable seperated by '&'.

Comment: @MichelChalfoun if you found my answer helpful and solve your problem please accept the answer so other people can know it solve your problem.

Comment: I would if it did solve the problem but it didn't. Thank you for your help but i ended up repairing Ofiice on my laptop and it fixed some issues in VBA including this one and everything's running smoothly now.